# mysql performance inner join vs duplicating fields

Tags: mysql

I have a user table and an item table.   The user table has a longitude and latitude column for their location.  If they add an item to the item table  i am also adding the longitude and latitude to the item table. (from the user table)   My question is ,do i need to do this or will the query perform efficiently if i just do an inner join from my user table to get the user.longitiude and user.latitude?  I have an index on the userId on the user table and it is a direct hit.

```
    SELECT user.longitude, user.latitude ,items.name, items.description
    FROM items 
    INNER JOIN user ON items.userId = user.userId
    WHERE items.category = "01";
```

Comment: whatever you do, have a good index strategy, do joins, and don't duplicate data (de-normalized) to other tables thinking you are doing the engine or yourself a favor

Comment: thanks for the advice.  i thought the joins would be the better approach